# How to upgrade Spring Tool Suite version instead of reinstalling?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ide, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I tried to upgrade Spring Tool Suite version from 3.9.9 to latest version (4.5.1) but i am not find the latest upgrade version.

I have checked existing STS IDE on help- >Check for Updates options, its having only STS 3 updates only i'm not found any STS 4 version update.

Currently i am using STS 3 only, instead of downloading and installing new STS 4 version is there any option for upgrade 3.x version 4.x.?

[image]

Comment: Try doing: the `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Udpate Sites` and press `Reload` on the STS update site.

Comment: Hi @procrastinator i tried already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading an existing installation from Spring Tool Suite 3.x to Spring Tools 4 is not supported and not recommended.

It might be possible, but it would involve manually uninstalling specific features and installing others for the corresponding Eclipse platform version. I would strongly recommend to not go down that path and start with a fresh Spring Tools 4 installation instead. If you have additional third-party plugins installed in your old STS3 install that you would like to get back into your new Spring Tools 4 install, there is support for that via the Import wizard in Eclipse (`Import... -> Install -> From Existing Installation`), but you need to carefully select the features that you would like to carry over.